# content push container with height 100%

Tags: html, css

I am trying that the content push the container and sidebar if it grow

but I want that always the height of all elements be at least the 100% of the screen

some ideas?

```
<body>
   <div class="sidebar_content_wrapper container_16">
      <div class="sidebar_left grid_3 omega">
         <p>blablabla</p>   
      </div>    
     <div class="content_wrapper grid_13 alpha">    
        <!-- many p tags here -->
     </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/YaTLG/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest "trick" to solve this problem is to set a background color, and have the shorter div the same color as the background color. this way, even if it runs short, it will still look like it fills the whole height.

if that's not an option, I believe you have to increase the height of the shorter element using javascript.

**jQuery example:**

```
$('.sidebar_left').css("height", $(".alpha").height() + "px");
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YaTLG/1/

Comment: thanks but the blue content, have to grow too  http://jsfiddle.net/YaTLG/2/ its not posible with css?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `table` instead of a `div`:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: its for a main web structure and i don´t know if it could be a good solution for that, anyways can you put the fiddle?